# How to allow /X/ instead of ?ID=X access in URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, directory

On me and my friends site we are wondering how to get ?ID=$ID just to show as a folder such as http://host/profiles/1/

We are guessing htaccess is required, but how is this done?
Thanks.

Comment: The slug part really makes that question different from this one (though I'm sure it's a duplicate of something else).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profiles/(\d+)/$ /profile?id=$1 [L]
```

It rewrites `globalschat.co.cc/profiles/1/` to `globalschat.co.cc/profile?id=1`

Comment: No, I want globalschat.co.cc/profile?id=1 to go as /profiles/1/ i know how to use GET.

Comment: @Jayden That's what this does. If a user types `globalschat.co.cc/profiles/1/` into their browser, the page `globalschat.co.cc/profile?id=1` will load from your server.

Comment: Well its not working, should i change profile to profile.php?id=1